# Use opacity instead of .toggle method to partly hide a div instead of hiding it completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, opacity

I have the following function:

```
// DIV scroller prev-next (jQuery)
function updateItems(delta)
{
    var $items = $('#group').children();
    var $current = $items.filter('.current');
    var index = $current.index();
    var newIndex = index+delta;
    // Range check the new index
    newIndex = (newIndex < 0) ? 0 : ((newIndex > $items.length) ? $items.length : newIndex); 
    if (newIndex != index){
        $current.removeClass('current');
        $current = $items.eq(newIndex).addClass('current');
        // Hide/show the next/prev
        $("#prev").toggle(!$current.is($items.first()));   
        $("#next").toggle(!$current.is($items.last()));    
    }
}
```

It iterates through a certain number of divs when the `#next` or `#prev` div is clicked. This all works great.

This part of the code is where I am stuck with:

```
// Hide/show the next/prev
$("#prev").toggle(!$current.is($items.first()));   
$("#next").toggle(!$current.is($items.last()));
```

What it does: When it is on the first div of the div to scroll through it will hide the `#prev` div (because there is nothing to go back to, it's on the first). The same for when it is at the last div, it will hide the `#next` div.

At the moment it will hide and show these divs because I have used `.toggle`. When testing this out, I found out it is more user-friendly not to hide the div but to make it semi-transparent (a bit like how a disabled button looks like).

So I was thinking of using `opacity: 0.5`. According to the jQuery site: `.css('opacity', '0.5');`, but how to implement this instead of the `.toggle`?

I am bit lost here, I hope someone on this site can help me out.

Comment: What is `delta` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I think you will also want to set the `disabled` attribute on the button with `0.5` opacity, I think it would be best to put the `opacity` rule in CSS, rather than in JavaScript. Then we will need only to toggle the `disabled` attributes of the buttons. The CSS would be:

```
button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

To toggle the `disabled` attribute, we can use jQuery's [.attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
const hasPrev = newIndex !== 0;
const hasNext = newIndex !== $items.length - 1;
  
$('#prev').attr('disabled', !hasPrev);
$('#next').attr('disabled', !hasNext);
```

Following is a full code example. Note that I have changed your `updateItems` function body somewhat as I was working on understanding it.

```js
function updateItems(delta) {
  const $items = $('#group').children();
  const currentIndex = $items.filter('.current').index();
  const newIndex = Math.max(0, Math.min(currentIndex + delta, $items.length - 1));

  $items.each(function (index) {
    $(this).toggleClass('current', index === newIndex);
  });
  
  const hasPrev = newIndex !== 0;
  const hasNext = newIndex !== $items.length - 1;
  
  $('#prev').attr('disabled', !hasPrev);
  $('#next').attr('disabled', !hasNext);
}

$('#prev').on('click', function () {
  updateItems(-1);
});

$('#next').on('click', function () {
  updateItems(1);
});
```

```css
button[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

li {
  background: #aaa;
  border: 5px solid #333;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}

li.current {
  background: #27bde2;
  border-color: #127790;
}

#group {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="group">
  <li class="current"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<button disabled id="prev" type="button">Previous</button>
<button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this extended solution, works like a charm and it even thought me a thing or two :) Kudos